# Return multiple aggregate columns in LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql, aggregate

I would like to translate the following SQL into LINQ:

```
SELECT
    (Select count(BidID)) as TotalBidNum,
    (Select sum(Amount)) as TotalBidVal
FROM Bids
```

I've tried this:

```
from b in _dataContext.Bids
select new { TotalBidVal = b.Sum(p => p.Amount), TotalBidNum = b.Count(p => p.BidId) }
```

but get an error "Bids does not contain a definition for "Sum" and no extension method "Sum" accepting a first argument of type "Bids" could be found.

How can I do this in LINQ?

Thanks

CONCLUDING:

The final answer was:

```
var ctx = _dataContext.Bids;

var itemsBid = (from b in _dataContext.Bids
               select new { TotalBidVal = ctx.Sum(p => p.Amount), TotalBidNum = ctx.Count() }).First();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this out. The variable b is an entity (for every iteration) while ctx is an entityset which has the extension methods you need.

```
var ctx = _dataContext.Bids;

var result = ctx
    .Select( x => new
    {
        TotalBidVal = ctx.Sum  ( p => p.Amount ),
        TotalBidNum = ctx.Count( p => p.BidId  )
    } )
    .First();
```

Comment: That did solve the error (although it seems like an unnecessary step - why is it needed?).  There was a problem with my Count(p=> p.BidID) - an error that p.BidID wasn't boolean.  I replaced it with Count() and now the query returns the correct sum and count but not as a single row.  The same row over and over - I presume as many times as there are rows in the Bids table.  How can I return a single row like in my original SQL query?

Comment: @BKahuna your query says "from b in _dataContext.Bids" thats an iteration. and you won't get one result even though u are trying to compute just the sum and count. You can end the lambda expression by calling First(). which will give u only one result like i've done.

Comment: @BKahuna please scroll my answer to the end and see the last call i make. i call the First() method which will ensure that i get only one row back (the sql generated is Top(1) )

Comment: When I do this I get a very inefficient `CROSS JOIN` SQL query. I need to use the `GroupBy( x => 1 )` trick to get an efficient query.

Answer (score 26):

You can write this query using `GroupBy`. The Lambda expression is as follows:

```
    var itemsBid = db.Bids
                     .GroupBy( i => 1)
                     .Select( g => new
                     {
                          TotalBidVal = g.Sum(item => item.Amount), 
                          TotalBidNum = g.Count(item => item.BidId)
                     });
```

Comment: This is simple but does the trick. By the way, I'd like to know the purpose of operator ".GroupBy( i => 1)". Why do we need that?

Comment: How do we know that the aggregate functions (`Sum`, `Count`) are calculated in one iteration? Could it not be iterating the group twice for this? (which is something I want to avoid)

Comment: @Thomas.Benz that expression groups the iterable by a constant, so that all elements of the iterable end up in a single group. Normally with GroupBy you provide a function so that the items are put into multiple different groups

Answer (score 0):

here's an alternative to scartag's solution:

```
(from b in _dataContext.Bids.Take(1)
select new 
{
    TotalBidVal = _dataContext.Bids.Sum(p => p.Amount), 
    TotalBidNum = _dataContext.Bids.Count()
}).Single();
```

Although there's no real reason you can't just say:

```
var result = new 
{
    TotalBidVal = _dataContext.Bids.Sum(p => p.Amount), 
    TotalBidNum = _dataContext.Bids.Count()
};
```

It hits the database twice, but its very readable

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using the [Aggregate Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/queries/aggregate-clause).

```
Aggregate t In _dataContext.Bids
Into TotalBidNum = Count(BidID),
     TotalBidVal = Sum(Amount)
```

If you're using Fx4+ or an extension dll for Fx2, you could also benfit from parallelism by using

```
Aggregate t In _dataContext.Bids.AsParallel
```